# How to fill up the entire internal contour using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In the following image, I'm trying to blacken out the internal design band with the name "jupiter"

[image]

[image]

MY DESIRED RESULT IS THE FOLLOWING

[image]

I've tried using RETR_EXTERNAL in and then fillPoly but it only blackens out the "white" portion(the band) of the binary image and not completely as i want it to.

How would I need to improvise to get it to blacken it out completely?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the masking technique to get your work done. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy
%matplotlib inline

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I = cv2.imread('E:\\Mukul\\others\\stof.png') #input image
#I.shape

I_cnt = np.where(I[:,:,2] == 255) #location of your bounding box region
I_mask = np.zeros_like(I[:,:,2])  # mask for the input image

I_mask[list(I_cnt[0]), list(I_cnt[1])] = 255
plt.imshow(I_mask, cmap = 'gray')
```

[image: bounding box region]

```
I_cnt1, _ = cv2.findContours(I_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
np.array(I_cnt1).shape # (1, 1420, 1, 2)


cv2.fillConvexPoly(I_mask, I_cnt1[0], 255)
plt.imshow(I_mask,cmap = 'gray')
```

[image: masked bounding box]

Since we want our bounding box region to be black, we will invert our image using `cv2.bitwise_not()` and then use `cv2.bitwise_and()` to get the required output image.

```
I_mask1 = cv2.bitwise_not(I_mask) 
out = cv2.bitwise_and(I_mask1, I[:,:,2])
plt.imshow(out,cmap = 'gray')
```

[image: output image]

Instead of using the above lines to find contours of our binary mask which can be used to fill our region using cv2.fillConvexPoly() , we can directly convert `I_cnt[0]`(array containing x-coordinate) and `I_cnt[1]`(array containing y-coordinate) to an array of (x,y) coordinates using the following code:

```
temp_list = []
for a, b in zip(I_cnt[0], I_cnt[1]):
     temp_list.append([a, b])
ctr = np.array(temp_list).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)

I_mask2 = np.zeros_like(I[:,:,2])
I_mask2[list(I_cnt[0]), list(I_cnt[1])] = 255
plt.imshow(I_mask2, cmap = 'gray')


cv2.fillConvexPoly(I_mask1, ctr, 255)
plt.imshow(I_mask2,cmap = 'gray')
```